# Delphi - Using interfaces from another unit

Tags: delphi

I am constantly getting the: Undeclared identifier for an interface type I have defined in another unit. 
Here is what I have:

```
unit Drawers;

interface

implementation

type

  IDrawer = interface
  ['{070B4742-89C6-4A69-80E2-9441F170F876}']
    procedure Draw();
  end;

end.
```

---

```
unit Field;

interface

uses
  Graphics, Classes, Drawers;

TField = class(TInterfacedObject, IField)
private
  FSymbolDrawer: IDrawer;
```

At FSymbolDrawer I get the complier error.

Of course I have the uses Drawers; in the unit where TField is defined.

What's this about?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the unit `Drawers` the type declaration of `IDrawer` has to be in the interface part of the unit. You have inserted it in the implementation part where it is only visible for in-unit declarations.

Here is the code:

```
unit Drawers;

interface

type

  IDrawer = interface
  ['{070B4742-89C6-4A69-80E2-9441F170F876}']
    procedure Draw();
  end;

implementation

end.
```

Comment: I can't believe I have overlooked this. I should go to bed now. Thank you.

Comment: @elector: Good night! Sleep well ;-)

Comment: Good catch! I totally missed that - I think I just automatically read it as `interface` because it followed `unit`. +1

Answer (score 1):

Which uses clause do you add `Drawers` to? It has to be in the `interface` uses clause (above the definition of `TField` that uses it).